# How to do this shape with UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, cashapelayer

I'm trying to convert my UIView to this shape with `UIBezierPath`, currently I'm only able to do the left bottom corner, seeking for help for adding other corners.

[image]

Code for left bottom only.

```
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.frame = self.innerLayout.layer.bounds

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        let radius: CGFloat = 50
        let rect = mask.bounds

        path.move(to: rect.origin)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + radius, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY), radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_2 * 3), clockwise: false)

        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.innerLayout.layer.mask = mask
```

I did couple of trials for adding other corners but my `UIView` got funny shapes. I simply added this by copying and pasting (and changing origin), I believe we will use this part of the code 4 times to add 4 corners

```
    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY)
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + radius, y: rect.maxY))
    path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY), radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI_2 * 3), clockwise: false)
```

Comment: Can you show the code that produced funny shapes?

Comment: @Sweeper just added but I don't think it's useful,  I just changed the origin and did some trials by drawing lines to different points

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a complete example to be run in Playground. Such geometric shapes are always tricky. It's very easy to get coordinates wrong or have an arc go into the wrong direction.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ConcaveConrnerViewController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 200, width: 200, height: 200)
        let subView = UIView(frame: frame)
        subView.backgroundColor = .red
        
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.frame = subView.layer.bounds

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        let radius: CGFloat = 50
        let rect = mask.bounds

        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + radius, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX - radius, y: rect.minY))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY), radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2 * 2), endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2 * 3), clockwise: false)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY - radius))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY), radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2 * 1), endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2 * 2), clockwise: false)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX + radius, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY), radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2 * 0), endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2 * 1), clockwise: false)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY + radius))
        path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY), radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2 * 3), endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2 * 0), clockwise: false)
        path.close()

        mask.path = path.cgPath
        subView.layer.mask = mask
        
        view.addSubview(subView)
        self.view = view
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ConcaveConrnerViewController()
```